# Make next button on AeroWizard disabled until another button is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using AeroWizard v2.2.3
, and I'm trying to find the button properties to make the Next button disabled until another button is pressed, I cannot find it anywhere ...

Perhaps there's any Event that I should catch when pressed the Next button and do a validation on?

I've tried to find the Button 'Next' Controls on my entire Designer.cs and nothing came up.

```
private void Btn01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str1 = tb01.Text;
    bool x;

    x = str1.EndsWith("/*");

    if (x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Contains /*");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Doesnt contains /* at the end", "Problem with path" ,MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    tb01.Text = "";
}
```

That's the code of the button that I want to click that will enable the Next button on the wizard, by default the button will be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a solution for that problem, when disabling the button using the VisualStudio properties:

```
Pointer --> Wizard Window --> 
AllowNext: False --> Go to designer.cs and you'll find the Property called: 
AllowNext = false;
```

Just take this one and put it under the another button of your choosing and after doing your code make it true like so:

```
this.<YourWizardPage>.AllowNext = true;
```